# Search for PATH=

Tags: bash

I used a program that set system setting and I can't find where my PATH environment variable was set, it's not set in:

- .bashrc
- .bash_profile
- .profile
- etc/paths

I have been trying to use a grep command:

`grep -rl "PATH=" /`

but the command is taking forever.

Does anyone have any suggestion on searching for where my PATH was assigned?

Comment: Check in `/etc/environment`

Comment: Noodle through [those ones](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html)

Comment: just search your home directory tree `grep -rl "PATH=" ~`

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command:

```
PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xlic "" 7>trace.out
```

Now, look through the file `trace.out`.  It will show you everytime PATH was modified along with the file name and line number which caused the change.

#### Example

```
$ grep PATH trace.out
+ /etc/profile:7:PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
+ /etc/profile:9:export PATH
```

This tells you that line 7 of the file `/etc/profile` set the PATH.

#### How it works

The short story is that this starts up a bash login session with tracing turned on.  For a longer explanation, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/591723/221266).